# Default PO Type to 'Drop Ship' not working properly

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to default the OrderType.POOrderType to POOrderType.DropShip.  I've tried altering the attributes in the customization manager to the following:

```
 [PXDBString(2, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true)]
 [PXDefault(POOrderType.DropShip)]
 [POOrderType.List()]
 [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Enabled = true)]
 [PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]
```

But upon insertion of a new record, it does nothing.  I've also tried using the CacheAttached event in a graph extension of POOrderEntry as follows:

```
  public class POOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<POOrderEntry>
  {
    [PXDBString(2, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true)]
    [PXDefault(POOrderType.DropShip)]
    [POOrderType.List()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Enabled = true)]
    [PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]
    protected virtual void POOrder_OrderType_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }

 }
```

This also does NOT work.

I've finally tried using the RowInserting event as follows

```
 protected virtual void POOrder_RowInserting(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertingEventArgs e)
 {
     POOrder poorder = (POOrder)e.Row;  
     if (poorder == null) return;
     poorder.OrderType = POOrderType.DropShip;
 }
```

This DOES default to DropShip, however, when I use the dropdown on the screen to change back to 'Normal', it empties all the fields, and the Type is also empty.  If I select Normal again, then it displays the data in the fields correctly.  I can't figure out what's going on here.  I always have to select the Type twice to get anything to show.  I can't see why the RowInserting event would cause this behavior...

Answer (score 0):

There is POOrder_OrderType_FieldDefaulting event in the POOrderEntry, where default order type is set.

```
protected virtual void POOrder_OrderType_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValue = POOrderType.RegularOrder;
}
```

It have 'higher priority' than PXDefault attribute (check T200 training for more information). 
So you need to override this event handler.